# Can a packer builder depend on another builder?

Tags: vagrant, packer

I am building a development environment for use with Vagrant, and it's working really well at the moment but from time to time I need to make some minor changes that aren't really part of the base system setup. So to speed up build times and iteration, I'd like to split my build into two, run in order:

1. Base image (OS, common tooling, configuration, etc.)
2. Vagrant specifics (developer tools, user configuration, etc.)

The former won't change very often, but the latter does. I'm using the VirtualBox builder, but I can't seem to figure out how to make one builder dependent on another – is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no builder dependency mechanism in Packer.

However since you can control what builder will run the build process, you can create simple wrapper script that will allow you to create the flow process you need.

So builder A will create base box and place final product in `/path` and builder B will use virtualbox image from `/path` as it's base to final Vagrant box. Your wrapper script should be the glue between builder A and builder B.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm currently doing, and it's working well, but it also means I can't use `push` which is a bit annoying. Thank you again for the insight!

Comment: I don't know anything about your dev environment, but if you based on Linux, you might take a look on Docker and container based dev environment.

Comment: We use docker as well, but use a VM as host. Since some of our devs are on Mac and Windows, we'd need boot2docker or something similar anyway and we've found just making sure everyone runs the same box makes everything that much easier.